# Как отследить закрытие дилога?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Здравствуйте я в активности открываю диалог

```java
folderOption dialog = new folderOption(defaultListAdapter,"");
dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"addFolder");
```

Как мне в этой же активности отследить закрытие этого диалога?

Comment: `folderOption` это что? класс? а что с маленькой буквы? Он от кого наследуется? от `AlertDialog`? код в студию!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В диалоге используются три кнопки, по слушателям которых и определяется работа с диалогом

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity, R.style.AlertDialog);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.setting165);  // заголовок
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.error64);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.setting271); // сообщение

    builder.setPositiveButton("Отменить", (dialog, id) -> {
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Удалить", (dialog, id) -> {
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton("Средняя скорость", (dialog, id) -> {
    });

    builder.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    dialog.show();
```